# Adding code to <body> tag with bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, html, bookmarklet

I am making a bookmarklet in which provides the user with navigation links on any page. I have the code I need, but am having trouble with the document.body.innerHTML.
Here's the code

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<style>
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
.myFloatBar{
bottom:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
position:fixed;

}
</style>
<div class="myFloatBar">
<a href="javascript: history.back();"><img src="https://6895974884731443be5a54869b555c239e101a11.googledrive.com/host/0B-uT9QTKkBoROS03Z1FxaHJrVGM/nav/back3.png" border="0"></a>
<a href="javascript: location.reload();"><img src="https://6895974884731443be5a54869b555c239e101a11.googledrive.com/host/0B-uT9QTKkBoROS03Z1FxaHJrVGM/nav/refresh3.png" border="0"></a>
<a href="javascript: history.forward();"><img src="https://6895974884731443be5a54869b555c239e101a11.googledrive.com/host/0B-uT9QTKkBoROS03Z1FxaHJrVGM/nav/forward3.png" border="0"></a>
</div>";
```

But no matter what I do, i can't seem to find the problem. 
I also tried running it through one of the "html encoders", thinking that the quotes were the issue, but that didn't seen to work either.
What did I did wrong?

Comment: The quotes are indeed the problem here. Replace the beginning/ending double quotes with single quotes and it should work. `document.body.innerHTML = '...';` Otherwise escape the double quotes inside the string.

Comment: Does the code syntax work as intended without the innerhtml?  Once the syntax is correct then set the innerhtml property and troubleshoot from there.  And yes the double quotes inside the double quotes would cause an issue.  Use inner single quotes instead\

Comment: This code will knock out the entire body's content -- is that intended?

Comment: I tried to replace the beginning and ending quotes with single quotes, escaping the double quotes, and using inner single quotes instead of double quotes. Nothing seems to be working. I pulled up the error console, and it said "SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF"

Comment: @JoshKG No it is not intended to REPLACE the body code, just add to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your double-quotes are a problem -- the fastest fix is to use single-quotes around your string. Additionally, using the innerHTML method on the body element will actually remove the entire contents of the body and replace it with your new elements. If you just want to append (add to) the body, use the insertAdjacentHTML method instead.

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<style>
    .myFloatBar{
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    }
</style>
<div class="myFloatBar">
<a href="javascript: history.back();"><img src="https://6895974884731443be5a54869b555c239e101a11.googledrive.com/host/0B-uT9QTKkBoROS03Z1FxaHJrVGM/nav/back3.png" border="0"></a>
<a href="javascript: location.reload();"><img src="https://6895974884731443be5a54869b555c239e101a11.googledrive.com/host/0B-uT9QTKkBoROS03Z1FxaHJrVGM/nav/refresh3.png" border="0"></a>
<a href="javascript: history.forward();"><img src="https://6895974884731443be5a54869b555c239e101a11.googledrive.com/host/0B-uT9QTKkBoROS03Z1FxaHJrVGM/nav/forward3.png" border="0"></a>
</div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

**working fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/9226/

you dont need `document.body.innerHTML`

call **CSS** in **head** tag